# How to retrieve the character between the "_" in the following string - ID_123_george using JAVA SCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, string

In the above string,  I want to retrieve 123 only which is between the _ (underscore) character. Can someone please help me using JAVA SCRIPT?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/WjgLh7/1

Answer (score 0):

You should split your string by `_` underscore delimiter. You will have an array which contains the parts of the "original" string. You can get the parts of the "original" string by using the indexes. You can see a snippet below.

**Code part:**

```
var str = 'ID_123_george'.split('_'); //SPLIT INTO ARRAY
str[1]; //1st index will give you 123
```